# SKEffectNode shader bug

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, shader, box2d, liquidfun

I'm developing a game using ***Sprite Kit*** and ***Liquid Fun*** (Google's implementation of Box2d with liquids).
After I applied a threshold shader to make the liquid more real, I stumbled in a strange behavior that can be seen on this video: [Current Behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3i_UMPBsXg)

The way it should behave can be seen on this video: [Normal Behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeEPf8e-pZA)

I'm applying the shader on a ***SKEffectNode*** that contains all the particles (***SKSpriteNodes***)

That's the code on my threshold shader:

```
void main()
{
 vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture,v_tex_coord);

 if(color.w > 0.4) {
  color = vec4(18.0/255.0, 122.0/255.0, 232.0/255.0, 1.0);
 } else {
  color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 }

 gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Does anyone have any clue of what is going on?